# fetching element of previous iteration in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, iteration, xslt-1.0

Is there way to fetch elements of previous iteration.

I have the following XML document (abbreviated for the better overview):

```
    <requests>
             <request>
                     <id>514</id>
                     <status>accepted</status>
                     <updated>"2013-10-07T12:00:51.508"</updated>
                     <query>
                        <![CDATA[Select column1 from table1]]>
                     </query>
             </request>
             <request>
                     <id>22</id>
                     <status>rejected</status>
                     <updated>"2012-11-07T12:00:51.508"</updated>
                     <query>
                        <![CDATA[Select column3 from table2]]>
                     </query>
             </request>
             <request>
                     <id>7523</id>
                     <status>accepted</status>
                     <updated>"2012-01-07T02:00:52.508"</updated>
                     <query>
                        <![CDATA[Select column8 from table3]]>
                     </query>
             </request>
             <request>
                     <id>84</id>
                     <status>accepted</status>
                     <updated>"2000-12-07T12:00:51.1"</updated>
                     <query>
                        <![CDATA[Select column1 from table1]]>
                     </query>
             </request>
             <request>
                     <id>999</id>
                     <status>accepted</status>
                     <updated>"2006-12-07T12:00:51.1"</updated>
                     <query>
                        <![CDATA[Select column1 from table1]]>
                     </query>
             </request>
                 .
                 .
                 .
     </requests>
```

Now I have to select all nodes with the status: "accepted" group them by the table and then by the column which is queried and for each column select only two requests with the most recent update time. The output should be ids of these node given as simple text. For example for the query 'Select column1 from table 1' 514 and 999 should be selected for output whereas 84 not. I have read about muenchian method but I could not apply it on the parsed text (in this case the text in query).
That is why I tried to figure out the way to obtain information from previous iteration so I can sort nodes by the given criteria and find id that I look for.

For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='requests']/*[local-name='request'][@status='accepted']" >
  <xsl:sort select="string(*[local-name()='query']/text())" order="text" data-type="number" />
  <xsl:sort select="@pdated" order="descending" data-type="number" />
  <xsl:value-of select="string(preceding-sibling::*[1]/*[local-name()='query']/text()) />
```

Now this works but not the way I want it, it returns the preceding sibling in the document but not the query text of previous iteration. Is something like this possible?
Thanks

Comment: An example of the input and the requested output would be useful. -- P.S. Is there a reason to use such awkward expressions as `*[local-name()='requests']` etc.?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Some people will avoid learning to use namespaces at all costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is a declarative language and while `for-each` might look like a procedural `for` loop there is no concept of that in the XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 specification. Therefore the concept of `previous iteration` does not exist either. Only XSLT 3.0 with the `xsl:iterate` provides something along those lines to allow processing of very large documents without loading the complete document tree into memory.

With XSLT 1.0 you will need to use a different approach, you would need to post the structure of the input samples you want to process and the corresponding result you want to create to allow us to help with concrete code.

Comment: With respect, this is not an answer.

Comment: I think the first paragraph is an answer to "is something like this possible", basically saying no. The second paragraph is an attempt to ask the poster to edit the question to allow us to be more helpful than saying "no", your understanding of `for-each` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read about muenchian method but I could not apply it on the
>   parsed text (in this case the text in query).

This is how you can apply Muenchian grouping based on parsed text - in this case, the column name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="req" match="request[status='accepted']" use="substring-before(substring-after(query ,'Select '), ' from')" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="requests/request[status='accepted'][count(. | key('req', substring-before(substring-after(query ,'Select '), ' from'))[1]) = 1]">
            <group>
                <xsl:value-of select="query"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to you example input, this will result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <group>Select column1 from table1</group>
  <group>Select column8 from table3</group>
</root>
```

Now you just need to sort the group members by update time and output the first two.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But I simply don't see hwo it separates the colums with the same name from different tables (for example :Select column1 from table1 and Select column1 from table2) because the key only extracts column name

Comment: @uztrew I guess I am missing something here: if you want a unique column/table combination, why is it necessary to parse the query at all? Isn't each unique query also a unique column/table combination?

Comment: What about blank spaces; "select col1 from table1" will be not grouped together with "select    col1     from  table1    ".

Comment: @uztrew It will, if you apply normalize-space() to them.

Comment: OK Thanks, but now back to the main question, if I could get information on previous iteration(s) - as @ Martin Honnen states it is the case with XSLT 3.0 - then I don't need muenchian grouping at all; in for-each loop I apply the sorting by query and then by the date which puts all nodes in the right order which allows the selection of two nodes with the most recent date by using the function position(). Is this right? (I cannot test it because I don't use XSLT 3.0)

Comment: @uztrew I don't see how having access to the previous iteration would help you with the current task (the process you describe would select only the first pair out of many possible). I think you are making a classic mistake of asking "how to do X using Y" instead of just "how to do X" (lookup *XY question*). IMHO, grouping the requests first and then sorting each group on its own is the most straightforward way to proceed here, regardless of the version.

Comment: if you sort the requests in the loop first by the query and then by the date you'll get the list where all requests with the same query are listed next to each other and arranged in chronological order. If a query of the previous differs from that of the current, it means that it is the first request of the current query  that should be outputted. That was my idea to solve this before I learned that there is no such way to implement it in XSLT 1.0

Comment: @uztrew This **can** be implemented in XSLT 1.0. But it has nothing to do with "accessing the previous iteration". You just need to produce the list first (into a variable), then process the list in another pass. In the second pass, the "previous iteration" of the first pass is now the preceding sibling. Anyway, such processing would be horribly inefficient compared to the alternative.